# Get unique values for string in R using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, distinct, distinct-values

I am summarising a table in R using the package dplyr. I'd like to see unique values only for a column in my table (Services.Offered). However, when I try the following code, I don't get unique values in this column-

```
sheetforr1=sheetforr %>%
              group_by(Account.Name, Service.managed.by.country) %>% 
              summarise(Services.Offered = unique(toString(Service.Level.2)),
                         POB = toString(Number.of.Users),
                         Start.Dates = toString(Provider.Start.Date),
                         End.Dates = toString(Provider.End.Date)) %>% 
              ungroup()
```

The result for the column 'Services.Offered' contains duplicates despite using 'unique' (for example: Cleaning, Gardening, Maintenance, Cleaning, Housekeeping, Housekeeping).

In addition, when I use 'distinct' instead of 'unique', I get an error message:

> no applicable method for 'distinct_' applied to an object of class "character"

Continuing with the example I just used, what I'd like is for to column `Services.Offered` to show: (Cleaning, Gardening, Maintenance, Housekeeping).

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: The readability of your code would be vastly improved by using proper indentation and whitespace around operators …

Answer (score 4):

You are putting `toString` inside of `unique` and so the full vector is being converted to a string first. Then, `unique` is returning that single string because it is the only one left. If you reverse the order, you will get the right behavior.

Since you didn't provide any sample data, here is an example:

```
set.seed(8675309)
df <-
  data.frame(
    group = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 5)
    , string = sample(letters[1:10], 15, TRUE)
  )



df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(strings = toString(unique(string)))
```

returns

```
  group    strings
  <chr>      <chr>
1     A b, e, h, c
2     B g, j, i, e
3     C i, f, c, h
```

I generally prefer to sort the results (so that "a, b, c" and "c, b, a" give the same entry), and I like more control, so I usually use something like:

```
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(strings = string %>% unique %>% sort %>% paste(collapse = ", "))
```

which gives

```
  group    strings
  <chr>      <chr>
1     A b, c, e, h
2     B e, g, i, j
3     C c, f, h, i
```